# IllegalAnnotationsException during obfuscating JAXB code with proguard

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations, proguard, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate JAXB code with proguard. This is the full Java class code:

```
  import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(propOrder =
{
    "setting", "subsystems"
})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ProfileImpl implements Profile
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    private final String version;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "subsystems")
    @XmlElement(name = "subsystem")
    private List<SubsystemImpl> subsystems;
    private SettingImpl setting;

    public ProfileImpl()
    {
        this.version = "1.0";
        this.name = "default";
    }

    public ProfileImpl(String name, SettingImpl setting, List<SubsystemImpl> subsystems, String version)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.setting = setting;
        this.version = version;
        this.subsystems = subsystems;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<SubsystemImpl> getSubsystems()
    {
        return subsystems;
    }

    public void setSubsystems(List<SubsystemImpl> subsystems)
    {
        this.subsystems = subsystems;
    }

    public SettingImpl getSetting()
    {
        return setting;
    }

    public void setSetting(SettingImpl setting)
    {
        this.setting = setting;
    }
}
```

But when I run the code I get:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 4 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Property c is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at private java.util.List org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.ProfileImpl.c
                at org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.ProfileImpl
                at private java.util.List org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.f.b
                at org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.f
Property d is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at private org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.d org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.ProfileImpl.d
                at org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.ProfileImpl
                at private java.util.List org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.f.b
                at org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.f
```

How I can solve the problem?

I tried this Proguard configuration in order to skip Class obfuscation:

```
<option>-keep public class org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.ProfileImpl{public *; private *;} -keepattributes Exceptions, *Annotation*, InnerClasses, Signature, SourceFile, EnclosingMethod -dontshrink -dontoptimize -keepparameternames</option>
```

Comment: Can you add entire `ProfileImpl` ?

Comment: `XmlElement` annotation is missing on `SettingImpl setting` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proguard to process annotations try to add the below to arguments

```
-keep public class javax.xml.bind.**
-keep public class org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.ProfileImpl implements org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.Profile
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#annotations

**Update**

I took the liberty to modify your code a bit as below.
Please check if after this modification and including parameter following the code makes any difference.

```
public class ProfileImpl implements Profile
{
    private String name;
    private final String version;
    private List<SubsystemImpl> subsystems;
    private SettingImpl setting;

    public ProfileImpl(){
        this.version = "1.0";
        this.name = "default";
    }

    public ProfileImpl(String name, SettingImpl setting, List<SubsystemImpl> subsystems, String version){
        this.name = name;
        this.setting = setting;
        this.version = version;
        this.subsystems = subsystems;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "version")
    public String getVersion(){
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version){
        this.version = version;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "subsystems")
    @XmlElement(name = "subsystem")
    public List<SubsystemImpl> getSubsystems(){
        return subsystems;
    }

    public void setSubsystems(List<SubsystemImpl> subsystems){
        this.subsystems = subsystems;
    }

    public SettingImpl getSetting(){
        return setting;
    }

    public void setSetting(SettingImpl setting){
        this.setting = setting;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tested this without result. Please see the updated post.

Comment: I get this java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.f.a(Unknown Source)

Comment: @PeterPenzov 've not tested the code. I hope above gives you an idea on how to proceed. Instead of fields, I've moved annotations to getter methods and I've excluded the same in configuration.
Rather you can skip the entire class, along with jaxb classes and annotations as I've updated in the configuration.

Comment: Can we keep the original code? I can't change it. Can we try to find some solution with Proguard configuration?

Comment: Sure. Did you try adding the new updated parameters?


`-keep public class javax.xml.bind.**
-keep public class org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.ProfileImpl implements org.settings.loader.osgi.impl.jaxb.Profile
-keepattributes *Annotation*`

Comment: Looks like it works but I have NPE in other Java class.

Answer (score 0):

Please add "name" and "version" in prop order too as access type define as Field

Comment: Cna you give some more information what do you mean?

Comment: @peter-penzov `private SettingImpl setting` are getting renamed upon obfuscation process so it's new name is something like `d`. On the other hand you specified `setting` in `propOrder` and jaxb unable to find it (because actually that field no longer exists). You should provide correct names for all mapped fields i.e set name attribute for annotations like  `@XmlAttribute(name="...")`

Comment: Yes, How I can configure Proguard not to rename these fields?